# Localization in iPhone not working on button click

Tags: iphone

I made an app for iPhone. In this user can change language on button click. but NSLoalizedString is not converting the value.

the code is

```
-(IBAction)btn1pressed:(id)sender {
    SecViewController *sec = [[SecViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SecViewController" bundle:nil];
    NSUserDefaults* userDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

    // NSLog(@"%@", [userDefaults objectForKey:@"AppleLanguages"]);


    languages =@"en";


    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:languages forKey:@"AppleLanguages"];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];     
    NSLog(@"%@", [userDefaults objectForKey:@"AppleLanguages"]);

    // NSLog(@"%@", NSLocalizedString(@"Subhash", nil));
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:sec animated:YES];
}

-(IBAction)btn2pressed:(id)sender {
    SecViewController *sec = [[SecViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SecViewController" bundle:nil];
    NSUserDefaults* userDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

    // NSLog(@"%@", [userDefaults objectForKey:@"AppleLanguages"]);


    languages = @"es";


    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:languages forKey:@"AppleLanguages"];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];     
    NSLog(@"%@", [userDefaults objectForKey:@"AppleLanguages"]);

    //  NSLog(@"%@", NSLocalizedString(@"Subhash", nil));

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:sec animated:YES];
}

-(IBAction)btn3pressed:(id)sender {
    SecViewController *sec = [[SecViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SecViewController" bundle:nil];
    NSUserDefaults* userDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

    // NSLog(@"%@", [userDefaults objectForKey:@"AppleLanguages"]);


    languages =@"ja";


    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:languages forKey:@"AppleLanguages"];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];     
    NSLog(@"%@", [userDefaults objectForKey:@"AppleLanguages"]);

    // NSLog(@"%@", NSLocalizedString(@"Subhash", nil));

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:sec animated:YES];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:languages,nil] forKey:@"AppleLanguages"];
```

Answer (score 0):

> Use NSLocalizedString(), for localization.
>
> Also give corresponding localization string.