# iOS Localization: Extract strings

Tags: ios, string, localization, extract

I find this tool `genstrings`, but it fails on line: `NSLocalizedString(key,comment);`

```
-(NSString*)toLocalizableString:(NSString*)key
               withComment:(NSString*)comment{
    NSString* stringResult = nil;
    if (key){
        stringResult = NSLocalizedString(key, comment);
    }
    NSLog(@"(*) key: <%@> (&) value: <%@> (*)",key,comment);
    return stringResult;
}
```

Also, steps of localization:

1. Find all strings and wrap them with `NSLocalizedStringFromTable`
2. Extract strings with `genstrings`
3. Put localizable files and find translations
4. well done!

I stuck at first step. 
How find all strings, that are needed to have translations?

Or i'm wrong?

Thanks for explanation!

Comment: Do you want to know how to localize strings ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12702612/localization-in-iphone-not-working-on-button-click/12702780#12702780

Comment: do you read my question? i write steps of localization, really. but my trouble is to find all strings and wrap them with `NSLocalized..`. I search for tool, that can automate some work for me

Answer (score 1):

I use [Ltools](https://github.com/percysnoodle/ltools) to help with this.  It's a two step process:

1. Search for `@"` in your code, and wrap the appropriate strings in `L()`
2. Run L.sh as part of your build process

This will make sure that every string that needs translating has a translation.

Comment: good choice, thanks! but i already have written my own script :)

Answer (score 1):

This is not exactly what you are searching for, but for me it doesn't make sense to translate *all* strings, e.g. you likely do not want to translate strings (`@""`) from an `NSPredicate`.

If you moved all relevant strings to NSLocalizableString / NSLocalizableStringFromTable, then I can recommend [Linguan](http://www.cocoanetics.com/apps/linguan/). You just pass in your XCode project and you are ready to start translating.

Comment: `if you moved all relevant strings...` - how to find all relevant strings?

Comment: Sorry to say that, but this is something you should start with right at the beginning (i.e. after creating the XCode project). Afterwards, you'll have to search manually for relevant strings.